# Constructing a graph with metric units using ggplot2

Tags: r, statistics

I constructed a data frame and scatterplot using the following code:

```
maltose_mg = c(0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2.0)

A540 = c(0, 0.090, 0.202, 0.329, 0.395, 0.468)

df = data.frame(maltose_mg, abs540)

ggplot(df, aes(x=maltose (mg), y=A540)) +
    geom_point(shape=1) +    
    geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

Unfortunately, R interprets the (mg) unit designation as a function call and A540 as an unknown object.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. The 'lm' function is for a line of best fit?

My goal is to construct an aesthetically pleasing scatterplot with an x-axis label of maltose (mg) and a y-axis label of A540.

Thanks,

~Caitlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define your data frame slightly more cleanly:

```
d <- data.frame(maltose_mg=maltose_mg, A540=A540)
```

(See `names(d)` and `names(df)` to see why. Note that naming a data frame `df` is possibly a bad idea, because `df` is also the name of a function.)

You can use the `xlab` and `ylab` functions to label the axes. (The `aes` tells you which columns of the data frame to map to which aesthetic; if you don't specify a label `ggplot2` *separately* picks the default axis label as the name of the column to which it is mapped.)

```
 ggplot(d, aes(x=maltose_mg, y=A540)) +
    geom_point(shape=1) +    
    geom_smooth(method=lm) +
    xlab("maltose (mg)") +
    ylab("A540")
```

You can also use `scale_x_continuous("maltose (mg)")`. Lots more good information in the [R Cookbook plotting section](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/).

Comment: I was taught (in physics) to use the style "Mass of Maltose/mg", since a bare number, eg "27", was really "27 mg" divided by "mg", leaving "27". YMMV.